# Intercepting TLS 1.2 connections

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle, tcp

I have an application that communicates with the server through a TCP TLS 1.2 connection. The app probably uses certificate pinning. I want to intercept this traffic.

Is there any way to decrypt the traffic except extracting master secret or RSA private key?
Will MITM approach (like [sslsplit](https://www.roe.ch/SSLsplit)) work here?

Answer (score 1):

In modern TLS, the private key of the leaf certificate won't let you decrypt previously recorded traffic, because modern TLS has DH (specifically, ECDHE) which provides PFS.

So you need to MiTM the connection or extract the per-connection ephemeral keys from the app.

Comment: Is MITM possible when the app check for expected certificate?

Comment: Not in a simple way.

Comment: is there any way except changing/removing cert check?

Comment: If it actually checks the expected cert or public key or their hash, no.

Comment: 1.3, which is not in the Q, has _only_ PFS, actually both ECDHE and FFDHE but the latter is rare now. 1.0 through 1.2 (all) have both xxDHE _and_ plain-RSA, although post-Snowden more people _prefer_ or _require_ xxDHE.